# How to use eloquent for get parent and child in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, parent-child

I want show gallery with parent and child.
I have code in controller to call model like this.

```
$galery  = GalleryModel::with(['gallerydetail'])->get();
```

And i have code for get table and column in model :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GalleryModel extends Model {
    protected $table        = 'tbl_gallery';
    protected $primary_key  = 'id_gallery';
    protected $fillable     = ['category_id','author_id','gallery_title','gallery_text','gallery_time','gallery_date','gallery_isdelete'];

    public function gallerydetail() {
        return $this->hasMany(GalleryDetail::class, 'gallery_id');
    }
}

class GalleryDetail extends Model {
    protected $table        = 'tbl_gallery_detail';
    protected $primaryKey   = 'id_detail_gallery';
    protected $fillable     = ['gallery_id','image'];
}
```

Gallery Detail can't show, when i call use ::with. I test with used dd and i can't get items.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta8cY.png).

Before i create this, i try to create for menu and its work, i can get data like this.
[result menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEv6j.png)

The code is same, but for gallery it's doesn't work. i don't know why, becase i can't get the problem or error. Please help me, thanks

My Data in Database
Table Galery

| ID Gallery | Gallery Title |
| --- | --- |
| 231 | Tes |

Table Detail Gallery

| Id Detail Gallery | gallery_id | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 231 | back.jpg |
| 2 | 231 | zone.jpg |

Comment: do you have data in the gallerydetails table ?

Comment: Seems like you don't have data in gallerydetails table but if it present and not being queried you might want to check the relation and define foreign and primary key properly.

Comment: I already update my question, my data in database like that. And i've create relation for id gallery and gallery id used designer in phpmyadmin

Comment: Sooo thannkyouu, i've got typo in mycode, from primary_key to primaryKey hehe. So thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add second argument in hasMany in gallerydetail() function, just add belongsTo function in your GalleryDetail Model.

GalleryModel:

```
public function gallerydetail() {
    return $this->hasMany(GalleryDetail::class);
}
```

GalleryDetail:

```
public function gallerymodel() {
    return $this->belongsTo(GalleryModel::class, 'gallery_id');
}
```